# HTML/PHP Code with quotation marks

Tags: php, html

I have a code I am developing but now I'm Stuck as I'm new to *PHP*.
When I use simple quotation marks it works but, I think this code is a little ugly and strange, I would like someone to review.

Code:

```
<?php echo"
                    <li class='light-blue'>
                        <a data-toggle='dropdown' href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>
                            <img class='nav-user-photo' src='../upload/avatar/$arqDir'>".$_SESSION['img'].">
                            <span class='user-info'>
                                <small>Bem Vindo,</small>       
                                    echo ".$_SESSION['nome']."; 
                            </span>

                            <i class='ace-icon fa fa-caret-down'></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class='user-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-close'>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#'>
                                    <i class='ace-icon fa fa-cog'></i>
                                    Cofigurações
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href='profile.html'>
                                    <i class='ace-icon fa fa-user'></i>
                                    Perfil
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class='divider'></li>

                            <li>
                                <a href='logout.php'>
                                    <i class='ace-icon fa fa-power-off'></i>
                                    Sair
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>";
                    ?>
```

Comment: Just use HTML without the `echo` and when you need PHP `<?=$_SESSION['img'] ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AbraCadaver said, this is one way it could be done:

```
<li class="light-blue">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <img class="nav-user-photo" src="../upload/avatar/<?php echo $arqDir . "/" . $_SESSION['img'];?>">
        <span class="user-info">
            <small>Bem Vindo,</small>       
                <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?>
        </span>

        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>

    <ul class="user-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-cog"></i>
                Cofigurações
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="profile.html">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                Perfil
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="logout.php">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-power-off"></i>
                Sair
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And another way could be:

```
<?php 
    echo '

    <li class="light-blue">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <img class="nav-user-photo" src="../upload/avatar/'. $arqDir . '/' . $_SESSION['img'].'">
        <span class="user-info">
            <small>Bem Vindo,</small>       
                '.$_SESSION['nome'].'
        </span>

        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>

    <ul class="user-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-cog"></i>
                Cofigurações
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="profile.html">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                Perfil
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="logout.php">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-power-off"></i>
                Sair
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove any confusion, use double quotes in your echo statements and use necessary escaping. For example

```
echo "<div class=\"boy\"> </div>";
```

OR

```
echo"<li class=\"boy\"> </li>";
```

The class name 'boy' was with double quotes too , so we just escaped it with backlash.
In case when you want to use arrays you just need to close and open quotes when required. For example

```
echo "The user is: ".$row['user'].":";
```

The above line will output something like:
The user is: user:

```
<?php echo"
<li class=\"light-blue\">
<a data-toggle=\"dropdown\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\">
<img class=\"nav-user-photo\" src=\"../upload/avatar/$arqDir\"".$_SESSION['img'].">
                            <span class=\"user-info\">
                                <small>Bem Vindo,</small>       
                                     ".$_SESSION['nome']."; 
                            </span>

                            <i class=\"ace-icon fa fa-caret-down\"></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class=\"user-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-close\">
                            <li>
                                <a href=\"#\">
                                    <i class=\"ace-icon fa fa-cog\"></i>
                                    Cofigurações
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href=\"profile.html\">
                                    <i class=\"ace-icon fa fa-user\"></i>
                                    Perfil
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class=\"divider\"></li>

                            <li>
                                <a href=\"logout.php\">
                                    <i class=\"ace-icon fa fa-power-off\"></i>
                                    Sair
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>";
                    ?>
```

I have tried to review and edit code accordingly. I hope you get this.

Comment: Voted down for adding more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Three method as I know is: 
 1. `<a href="google.com"> <?php echo $variable; ?> </a>`
 2.

```
<?php 
   echo "<a href=\"google.com\"> $variable </a>";
?>
```

3.

```
<?php 
echo <<< LINK 
<a href="google.com"> $variable </a> 
LINK; 
... 
?>
```

I prefered third solutions. In my opinion is the most clear.
In your case should looks like:

```
echo <<< html
<li class='light-blue'>
                    <a data-toggle='dropdown' href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>
                        <img class='nav-user-photo' src='../upload/avatar/$arqDir'>$_SESSION[img]>
                        <span class='user-info'>
                            <small>Bem Vindo,</small>       
                                $_SESSION[nome] 
                        </span>

                        <i class='ace-icon fa fa-caret-down'></i>
                    </a>

                    <ul class='user-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-close'>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#'>
                                <i class='ace-icon fa fa-cog'></i>
                                Cofigurações
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href='profile.html'>
                                <i class='ace-icon fa fa-user'></i>
                                Perfil
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class='divider'></li>

                        <li>
                            <a href='logout.php'>
                                <i class='ace-icon fa fa-power-off'></i>
                                Sair
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
html;
```